# Multitenancy in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, multi-tenant

I am building a Multitenant MongoDb system. How to switch between Db's depending upon request. I am using MongoDb with Node js using MongoDb native Driver.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your [MongoClient](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/mongoclient.html) object has a method `.db(dbname)` which returns a reference to a different database object using the same connection.

But you might want to consider to just store the data of all tennants in the same collections of a single database and add a field `tennant` to every document which you then include in every query. When you have individual collections or even an individual databases per tenant, the maintenance effort for your database administrator increases linearly with the number of tenants you have, because many maintenance and configuration tasks (like configuring sharding, for example) need to be performed on every collection of every database separately.